# How can I use AWS Boto3 to get Cloudwatch metric statistics?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm working on a Python 3 script designed to get S3 space utilization statistics from AWS CloudFront using the Boto3 library.

I started with the AWS CLI and found I could get what I'm after with a command like this:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --namespace AWS/S3 --start-time 2017-03-06T00:00:00Z --end-time 2017-03-07T00:00:00Z --statistics Average --unit Bytes --region us-west-2 --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=foo-bar Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage --period 86400 --output json
```

This returns the data I would expect.  Now I'd like to do the same thing in Python 3 / Boto3.  My code thusfar is:

```html
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import boto3

seconds_in_one_day = 86400  # used for granularity

cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/S3',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'BucketName',
            'Value': 'foo-bar'
        },
        {
            'Name': 'StorageType',
            'Value': 'StandardStorage'
        }
    ],
    MetricName='BucketSizeBytes',
    StartTime=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7),
    EndTime=datetime.now(),
    Period=seconds_in_one_day,
    Statistics=[
        'Average'
    ],
    Unit='Bytes'
)

print(response)
```

When I run this, I get a valid response but no datapoints (it's an empty array).  They seem to be identical except the Python method doesn't seem to have a place for the region, where the command line requires it.

One more thing I tried:  my code is computing the dates for the last date versus the command line where they are hard coded.  I did try hard coding the date just to see if I would get data back, and the result was the same.

So my questions are these:

Is the method I'm using in Boto / Python equivalent to the command line?
Assuming they are, what could I be missing?

Comment: `datetime.now` returns local time. CW understands UTC time. You need `datetime.utcnow`. The timestamps in your AWS CLI version of the command look like UTC timestamps. Also, as a rule of thumb, always pass `region_name` to `boto3.client`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, bruce? I tried almost all the suggestions below to no avail. Same result - no data is returned but i can see the data when I go to the aws console cloudwatch graph.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one very good example to get data from cloudwatch in python using boto3.  I had to spend few hours to get it working, but it should be easy to refer now.

```
def get_req_count(region, lb_name):
    client = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name=region)
    count = 0
    response = client.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace="AWS/ApplicationELB",
            MetricName="RequestCount",
            Dimensions=[
                {
                    "Name": "LoadBalancer",
                    "Value": lb_name
                },
            ],
            StartTime=str_yesterday,
            EndTime=str_today,
            Period=86460,
            Statistics=[
                "Sum",
            ]
    )   

    #print(response2)        
    for r in response['Datapoints']:
        count = (r['Sum'])

    return count
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work now for boto3 1.24, not able to get this data

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've done:

```
client = boto3.client(service_name='cloudwatch', region_name='us-east-1')

        response = client.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace = 'AWS/EC2',
            Period = 300,
            StartTime = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds = 600),
            EndTime = datetime.utcnow(),
            MetricName = metricVar,
            Statistics=['Average'], Unit='Percent',
            Dimensions = [
                {'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': asgName}
            ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, so the region looks like a prime suspect here.

You can set it when creating the client with:

```
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='us-west-2')
```

If this is not set, boto will try to get the region from the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` env variable first and then the `~/.aws/config` configuration file. Try checking those to see what is the default region set.

Comment: It's a good idea.  I had planned on looking into the source to see if maybe the parameter could be added.  I haven't researched the revision history; perhaps the region is a new requirement and that's why it's not in boto3.

Comment: I'm also noticing some other oddities with even the working command line code.  It doesn't work correctly when you pass in certain parameters that are right out of the docs, so I'm starting to think it's just a new and buggy api.

Answer (score 1):

I have a viable work-around in case someone else needs this, but I still want to find a non-kludgy answer if one exists.  It may not.  I decided I'd just generate the command line and use python to run it and retrieve the json result - the same net result.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

command = "aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --namespace AWS/S3 --start-time {} --end-time {} --statistics Average --unit     Bytes --region {} --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value={}   Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage --period 86400 --output json"

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    region = s3_client.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket.name)
    region_name = region['LocationConstraint']

    start_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
    start_date_str = str(start_date.date()) + 'T00:00:00Z'
    end_date = datetime.now()
    end_date_str = str(end_date.date()) + 'T00:00:00Z'
    cmd = command.format(start_date_str, end_date_str, region_name, bucket.name)
    res = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    bucket_stats = json.loads(res.decode('ascii'))
    if len(bucket_stats['Datapoints']) > 0:
        print(bucket_stats['Datapoints'])
```

Comment: This is partly not robust because you don't separate parameters correctly. It might work now, but if something has a space, this script will break.

Also, this is open to all kinds of injection attacks if you are not completely in control of what goes into this script.

Comment: I do not consider this the correct solution and that it is definitely not fit for any kind of production use.

I know that not everything has to be strictly production ready, but it would be nice if this was noted in the post.

This is completely doable with boto3 in a safer and more robust way.

Comment: Comments were getting out of hand here, so many of them have disappeared. Please [keep it constructive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and focus on the technical issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is your command `cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')`. The default region is east-1. So you could use something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import boto3

def credentials_AWS (account):
  
   if (account == 'account1'):
       aws_access_key_id = "key id east"
       aws_secret_access_key = 'east secret_access_key'
       region_name = 'us-east-1'
   elif (account == 'account2'):
       aws_access_key_id = "key id west"
       aws_secret_access_key = 'west secret_access_key'
       region_name = 'us-west-2'
    
   return aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, region_name
    

def connect_service_aws (service, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, region_name):


     aws_connected = boto3.client (service,
                                  aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id,
                                  aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key,
                                  region_name = region_name)
             
     return aws_connected


def get_metrics(account):

  seconds_in_one_day = 86400  # used for granularity

  #cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

  aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, region_name = credentials_AWS (account)
    
   
   cloudwatch = connect_service_aws ('cloudwatch', aws_access_key_id, 
                 aws_secret_access_key, region_name)

  response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/S3',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'BucketName',
            'Value': 'foo-bar'
        },
        {
            'Name': 'StorageType',
            'Value': 'StandardStorage'
        }
    ],
    MetricName='BucketSizeBytes',
    StartTime=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7),
    EndTime=datetime.now(),
    Period=seconds_in_one_day,
    Statistics=[
        'Average'
    ],
    Unit='Bytes'
  )

  print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

This script solves the problem. A detailed explanation can be found below the script.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import boto3

seconds_in_one_day = 86400  # used for granularity

bucket_name = "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"

# Valid values for storage type, as per [AWS S3 Metrics and Dimensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html)
# StandardStorage, IntelligentTieringFAStorage, IntelligentTieringIAStorage, IntelligentTieringAAStorage,
# IntelligentTieringAIAStorage, IntelligentTieringDAAStorage, StandardIAStorage, StandardIASizeOverhead,
# StandardIAObjectOverhead, OneZoneIAStorage, OneZoneIASizeOverhead, ReducedRedundancyStorage,
# GlacierInstantRetrievalSizeOverhead GlacierInstantRetrievalStorage, GlacierStorage, GlacierStagingStorage,
# GlacierObjectOverhead, GlacierS3ObjectOverhead, DeepArchiveStorage, DeepArchiveObjectOverhead,
# DeepArchiveS3ObjectOverhead, DeepArchiveStagingStorage, and ExpressOneZone

storage_types = [
    "StandardStorage",
    "IntelligentTieringFAStorage",
    "IntelligentTieringIAStorage",
    "IntelligentTieringAAStorage",
    "IntelligentTieringAIAStorage",
    "IntelligentTieringDAAStorage",
    "StandardIAStorage",
    "StandardIASizeOverhead",
    "StandardIAObjectOverhead",
    "OneZoneIAStorage",
    "OneZoneIASizeOverhead",
    "ReducedRedundancyStorage",
    "GlacierInstantRetrievalSizeOverhead",
    "GlacierInstantRetrievalStorage",
    "GlacierStorage",
    "GlacierStagingStorage",
    "GlacierObjectOverhead",
    "GlacierS3ObjectOverhead",
    "DeepArchiveStorage",
    "DeepArchiveObjectOverhead",
    "DeepArchiveS3ObjectOverhead",
    "DeepArchiveStagingStorage",
    "ExpressOneZone"
]

cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

for storage_type in storage_types:
    response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace='AWS/S3',
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'BucketName',
                'Value': bucket_name
            },
            {
                'Name': 'StorageType',
                'Value': storage_type
            }
        ],
        MetricName='BucketSizeBytes',
        StartTime=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7),
        EndTime=datetime.now(),
        Period=seconds_in_one_day,
        Statistics=['Average'],
        Unit='Bytes'
    )
    if "Datapoints" in response and response.get("Datapoints", []):
        print(f"Storage Type: {storage_type}, Metric Response: {response}")
    else:
        print(f"Storage Type: {storage_type}, no data")
```

According to [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch/client/get_metric_statistics.html), **all the dimensions of a metric must be specified in requests**. If a dimension is not specified boto3 does not raise exceptions, but it returns an **empty response**.

Empty responses are returned also if you specify a bucket that is **outside the region of the cloudwatch client**, or a bucket to which you **don't have access**.

> If the metric contains multiple dimensions, you must include a value for each dimension. [...] If a specific combination of dimensions was not published, you can’t retrieve statistics for it.

Values for each dimension can be found in AWS documentation: for example, [AWS S3 Metrics and Dimensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html)  and [Amazon DynamoDB Metrics and Dimensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html).

If no data point is available, it could suggest that there are no objects in the StandardStorage storage type requested by the original poster; therefore, the proposed script iterates through all valid storage classes and computes the required metric for each of them.

Answer (score -2):

i was able to resolve this. you need to specify the Dimensions parameter in the boto3 call.

Comment: you'd better put some explanation

Comment: Please add code and/or a description of what exactly had to be done to resolve the issue. In its current state, this looks like an edit to the parent post or a comment. Please see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 'Dimensions': [
                        {
                            'Name': 'string',
                            'Value': 'string'
                        },
              ]