# List s3 buckets with its size in csv format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to list the s3 buckets with its size in csv.

- Bucket Name      Size
- Bucket A          2 GB
- Bucket B          10 GB

Looking for something like this...

I can list the buckets with the below code.

```
def main():
    with open('size.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow([
            'Bucket Name',
            'Bucket Size'

        ])
        with open('accountroles.json') as ec2_file:
            ec2_data = json.load(ec2_file)
        region_list = ['us-west-1']
        for region in region_list:
            for index in range(len(ec2_data['Items'])):
                Account_Number = ec2_data['Items'][index]['Aws_Account_Number']
                Account_Name = ec2_data['Items'][index]['Acc_Name']
                ARN = ec2_data['Items'][index]['ARN']
                b = get_assume_arn_to_keys(Account_Number,Account_Name,ARN)
                #ds_client = boto3.client('s3',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id=``,aws_secret_access_key=``,aws_session_token=``)
                ds_client = boto3.client('s3',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id=b[1],aws_secret_access_key=b[2],aws_session_token=b[3])

                #s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

                bucket_list = ds_client.list_buckets()

                for bucket in bucket_list['Buckets']:
                    ************
                     ??????????
                    writer.writerow([
                        Account_Name,
                        #region,
                        bucket['Name'],
                        Bucketsize

                                   ])


main()
```

I can list the bucket. Please help me how to proceed with getting the sizes. 
I have referred few and seems the size can be got with CW metrics. Is there any way.

Help me on the script.

Edit / Update:

```
                bucket_list = ds_client.list_buckets()

                for bucket in bucket_list['Buckets']:

                    try:
                        lifecycle = ds_client.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
                        rules = lifecycle['Rules']
                    except:
                        rules = 'No Policy'
                    try:
                        encryption = ds_client.get_bucket_encryption(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
                        Encryptiontype = encryption['ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration']['Rules']
                    except:
                        Encryptiontype = 'Not Encrypted'

                    print(bucket['Name'], rules, Encryptiontype)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at S3 Inventory. Maybe that's fitting for your use case as well.

Comment: The CW metrics are less useful because it only gets one data point every 24 hours for S3.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to go with CW metrics as I mentioned in the Post... Any other?

Comment: How many objects are in the bucket? If it is huge (tens of thousands), I would recommend [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file of all objects in a bucket (including their size).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have atleast 200 buckets and each bucket size varies from 1GB to 4TB with multiple objects... Is there a way I can add it to my script. Because I have all properties of the bucket pulled already. I just want the new colum with size in csv.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the size already provided by Amazon CloudWatch metrics? Your question does not mention why this solution is not acceptable.

Comment: I have already scripted to get the list of S3 buckets and all its properties like logging, versioning etc in a csv. I also wanted to add one more column in the csv to get the bucket size, so whenever I run the script I can get ALL about the Buckets.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [list_objects()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects).
Using that listobject you're able to get the key and size of each object using selector response['Contents'][]['size'] it holds the in bytes size of the object.

The downside of it is that in case you have too many objects in the bucket it might take time to iterate in order to get the total bucket size.

Comment: Yes, I ave buckets with TB... So it would take longer... Any other suggestions plz

Comment: Is it multiple small block of data that forms the TB? because you still can use the object listed but change on how you will do it; for example you can host your script in an instance overnight to harvest those data

Comment: refer to this script that i created.. github.com/edcelvista/python-aws/blob/master/S3BucketScan.py – Edcel Cabrera Vista 15 secs ago   Edit   Delete

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will calculate the size of a bucket. I've done it as a function so you can incorporate it into your code:

```py
import boto3

def bucket_size(bucket):
    size = 0

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket = bucket)

    for page in page_iterator:
        for object in page['Contents']:
            size += object['Size']

    # Return size in MB (rounded)
    return size // 1024

# Call function
size = bucket_size('my-bucket')
print(size)
```

I used a page iterator just in case you have more than 1000 objects in a bucket.

(In addition to the license granted under the terms of service of this site the contents of this post are licensed under MIT-0.)

Comment: Thanks for this.. Let me incorporate with my code and update You.

Comment: Its giving the size in Bytes.. Just tested the code. I haven't yet incorporated with my code. Just before that, how do we make it print in GB instead of bytes. Thanks

Comment: Divide by (1024 * 1024) because 1024 bytes = 1MB and 1024MB = 1GB.

Comment: Thanks for that..  When I am trying the code seperately it gets the bucket size.. But I want to incorporate within the for loop to get it listed along with other properties.. I have updated the code in the post. Please check.  """ I have added the for loop in the post". Please help me to incorporate your code inside that loop" as I wanted to get for multiple buckets in a single go.

Comment: I have simplified the code because I discovered that any region can be used to calculate bucket size. Please note that it now returns MB (rounded to zero decimal places). Divide this by 1024 to obtain GB.

Comment: You can use the function by calling it as shown in the second-last line. For example, you could use: `size = bucket_size(bucket['Name']) / 1024`

Comment: Thanks for that and its working.. Will make my amendments to it. One quick question, its taking hours for larger bucket. Is there any way to get it quicker? Because I have 200+ buckets and every bucket is huge. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), or use the bucket size provided by [Amazon CloudWatch metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html#s3-cloudwatch-metrics).

Comment: I have set up the inventory. It seems will take time for the same.. Could You please help me with CW metrics to incorporate with my code.

Comment: Some good resources: [How can I get the size of an Amazon S3 bucket?](https://serverfault.com/a/710080/267968) and [How can I use AWS Boto3 to get Cloudwatch metric statistics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42701110/174777) and [S3 Monitoring Step #1 – Bucket Size and Number of Objects – Data Engineering and Analytics in Cloud](http://cloudsqale.com/2018/10/08/s3-monitoring-step-1-bucket-size-and-number-of-objects/). Some of them show the AWS CLI equivalent, which you could convert into Python and boto3. There's also some boto3 samples in there.